# Boiling water animation

Tags: animation, unity

I want to make boiling water animation. After that I want to use in Unity project.  I'm new to blender so help would be really appreciated!

Comment: when you say you want to use it in unity, do you want a real object, or just a video of the boiling?

Comment: A real object like a bowl with boiling water inside.

Comment: I tried this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqhAFKKro5w. Then I created animation using Action Editor and project saved in .fbx format. But in Unity the animation is not working. Maybe there is another way to create boiling water animation which will work in Unity?

Comment: I've given this thought myself in the past, but never actually tried it. What I have been thinking about is a particle system that emits "bubbles" that are set as fluid outflows. It should produce a fluid domain animation with moving holes. BUT I haven't tried it and don't know whether it would be compatible with Unity.